# golang database updating a non-existing entry

Tags: database, postgresql, go, error-handling

I have a function to update a database entry as follows. The logic is that updating a non-exisitng entry returns error. Somehow I find the code a bit verbose on error handling. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

```
func (adb *AppDB) UpdateTicket(t Ticket) error {                                   
    result, err := adb.db.NamedExec(`UPDATE ticket SET detail=:detail, start_time=:start_time, end_time=:end_time, priority=:priority WHERE id=:id;`, &t) 
    if err != nil {                                                                
        return err                                                                 
    }                                                                              
    nRows, err := result.RowsAffected()                                            
    if err != nil {                                                                
        return err                                                                 
    }                                                                              
    if nRows == 0 {                                                                
        return fmt.Errorf("Ticket:%s does not exist for update", t)                
    }                                                                              
    return nil                                                                     
}
```

Comment: You may use any golaang ORM . I would highly recomend https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to make it less verbose and easy to maintain I would highly recomend using ORM. You may try https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm

Named return might make it less verbose, but this is not a best practise for lot of scenarios

```
func (adb *AppDB) UpdateTicket(t Ticket) (err error) {
    var result ResultType
    var nRows int
    if result, err = adb.db.NamedExec(`UPDATE ticket SET detail=:detail, start_time=:start_time, end_time=:end_time, priority=:priority WHERE id=:id;`, &t); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if nRows, err = result.RowsAffected(); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if nRows == 0 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("Ticket:%s does not exist for update", t)
    }
    return
}
```